# Nexus 6 and Nexus 9 Screen density

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

Can anyone tell me which Drawable does Nexus 6 and Nexus 9 support xxhdpi or xxxhdpi? I also want to whether Nexus 6 supports large- hdpi or anything else?

I searched in google but found no luck?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

from http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html

> Nexus 6 has a quantized density of 560 dpi, which falls in between the
>   xxhdpi and xxxhdpi primary density buckets.
>
> For the Nexus 6, the platform will scale down xxxhdpi assets, but if
>   those aren’t available, then it will scale up xxhdpi assets.
>
> drawable-xxxhdpi/ # Higher resolution assets for Nexus 6
>
> The Nexus 9 is a premium 8.9” tablet with a screen size of 2048 x 1536
>   pixels (288 ppi), which translates to 1024 x 768 dip. This is a 4:3
>   aspect ratio, which is unique compared to earlier tablets. The Nexus 9
>   falls into the xhdpi density bucket, and you should already have
>   assets in the drawable-xhdpi folder.

Comment: Thanks @Chirag Raval. But can u tell me whether Nexus 6 supports Large - HDPI or Xlarge - Mdpi.

Comment: @David did you find out which folder does nexus 6 support?

Comment: No @Saawan . Did not find a solution for that. But I found an alternative way. Please refer https://github.com/intuit/sdp . This helped me. Might help you too.

Comment: @David - FWIW, this can be determined by running android emulator with the specs that are reported by the phone [Nexus 6 = 1440x2560, density=560dpi], supplying only `drawable-hdpi` folder, and seeing whether the image appears. [I believe it always will, if it can find the image in any folder.] If so, then the Android version you are testing with "pre-scales it" for the device (as it reads resource into memory). OR if you really want to supply just one version of an image, put it in `drawable-nodpi`, and let Android scale it "at run-time" (as it draws that page).

Answer (score 1):

Nexus 6 is under the xxxhdpi device category just like the Nexus 6P,
Nexus 9 comes under the xhdpi category.

Source: https://design.google.com/devices/

Comment: Nexus 6P is a xxxhdpi device, but not a xhdpi device

Comment: That source may be outdated. Nexus 6 has been reported to declare itself as the newer "in-between" `560dpi` density.

Comment: Sorry I had a comma there but I meant the Nexus 6 had the same density as the Nexus 6P, @ToolmakerSteve do you have any sources that states that? because the source page I stated is from a list maintained by Google and has so far been pretty accurate and has been my goto list, if its outdated I rather edit my answer and state in bold that it might be outdated.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I think I understand what you mean by 560 dpi declaration, the thing is 560 dpi device downscale xxxhdpi resources and if you look at the int representation of density you can see its 3.5 which means its in between 3 (xxhdpi) and 4 (xxxhdpi) and usually a 3.5 means 560dpi which downscales resources for 4(true xxxhdpi)

Comment: @king_below_my_lord - you slightly misunderstand what happens. *if there are no 560 dpi (3.5) resources provided*, **then**, yes, the device will downscale from xxxhdpi (4.0).  This is no different than the behavior of *any* resolution, which will downscale (or upscale) from a nearby alternative, when the *exact* resolution resource is not available. (Given that app developers don't usually include the `drawable-560dpi` folder, in practice the result is what you say.)