# Android App - Designing for HTC Nexus 9 Screen Resolution

Tags: android, tablet, screen-resolution

I've designed my app for mobile phone devices, but the sizes and resolutions of many of my images look horrible while displaying on an HTC Nexus 9 tablet.

What is the required width (in pixels) for my images so that they fill the screen properly (assuming the image is filling the width of the screen)?

What folder in my app project should these images be stored in?

Do I have to make any changes to my .xml layout files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Max width is 1536px, place all your images in the xhdpi folder. You can overwrite whatever you already have in there, even if they're already drawn at the standard width of 720px. They scale the same on both mobile phones and the Nexus 9. Trust me. It just works.

[Nexus 6 and Nexus 9 Screen density](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602229/nexus-6-and-nexus-9-screen-density)