# How to handle multiple resources in react native?

Tags: react-native

**Explanation:** I want to display an image using  tag in react native.I put a single image in my src directory and load local image from it in my  tag.It working fine.

**Issue**

If we compare this structure with our android drawable directories then i there is some doubts i have.

In android, There are five drawable directory. There are five different drawable directories which is list below:

drawable-mdpi
drawable-hdpi
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi
drawable-xxxhpi

In all the directories an image file lies with the same name. According to the device density it used the resources which we put into the drawable directories.

**Question**

My question is if we create an application using react native. 
What is the structure of the drawable directories to satisfy the requirement of the different densities devices?

Comment: You create your images with an `@2x` and `@3x` suffix to support the different densities - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already suggested in this link: 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html

if you want to have different picture sizes for different density levels you can mark them with @2x, @3x, etc

Also you can add -ios and -android to use them only in their respective devices.

if you already have a native app and want to integrate React-Native pages in it, then it would be no problem as you already have drawable folders and can access their pictures by just calling the picture name (without its relative path e.g. call 'icon' NOT './android/drawable/icon')

Comment: for example i have 5 image namely logo.png with different dimention. Where should i need to put all 5 images? I mean inside the my application directory or in android/app/src/res/drawable directory?

Comment: Thanx for you replay.  I think the 2x and 3x it is for iOS what about for the android?

Comment: @MilanGajera The easy way is to put them in your drawable folders yourself just as you do normally. You can also do the same for ios and have your resources be handeled natively

Answer (score 6):

To further clarify, the image sizes correspond like this:

- 1x: **mdpi** Android devices (160 dpi)
- 1.5x: **hdpi** Android devices (240 dpi)
- 2x: Phone 4, 4S, 5, 5c, 5s, 6, **xhdpi** Android devices (320 dpi)
- 3x: iPhone 6 plus, **xxhdpi** Android devices (480 dpi)
- 3.5x: Nexus 6 (560dpi): in-between xxhdpi and xxxhdpi, will scale down xxxhdpi, see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602229/nexus-6-and-nexus-9-screen-density)
- *I presume 4x would be xxxhdpi*

Information source: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pixelratio